# How to remove all files from all folders without any extension?

Tags: command-line, magento

My magento folder have backup innumerousfiles without any extension (Backup files), how to remove this files?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that "without extension" means "without a dot in the name", correct? If so, just search for files without a dot in the name

```
find /my/directory -not -iname '*.*'
```

After you checked that this search *only* finds files you want to delete, delete the files

```
find /my/directory -not -iname '*.*' -exec rm {} \;
```

`-exec` basically means, "with each of the files found, do this:", and `{}` represents the file currently handled.